# Understanding proof of Hahn-Jordan Decomposition

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Theorem**: If $\nu$ is a signed finite measure on $\mathcal{f}$, then there is an $E \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\nu$ is totally positive on $E$ and totally negative on $E^c$.

**Proof (part of)**:

Let $$s = \sup \{ \nu(A) \mid \nu \text{ is totally positive on A } \}$$ Let $(s_k)$ be a stricting increasing sequence tending ot s and let $A_k \in \mathcal{F}$ be such that $\nu$ is totally positive on $A_k$ and $\nu(A_k) > s_k$. Let $E = \cup_k^\infty A_k$. Then $\nu$ is totally positive on $E$ and $\nu(E) = s < \infty$.

---

This is just a part of the proof, but could someone explain how the author reached the conclusion of "$\nu$ is totally positive on $E$ and $\nu(E) = s < \infty$. "

Comment: Your quotes of proof missed lot of information. The official proof should have $A_k$'s are disjoint.

Comment: @runaround I've printed the proof word for word, I'm not missing anything. Even with the $A_k's$ disjoint, I don't see the conclusion

Comment: What book are you copying the proof from?